# Error in Python with StingVar() when used with Tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I am working with a Tkinter Script. I am able to retrieve the value obtained from the button press and then input that as string to the entry. But the entry.get results in error.

Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import os
import sys
import re
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *



def style_check():
    source = e1.get()
    listfiles = os.listdir(source)

    for f in listfiles:
        filepath = os.path.join(source+'\\'+f)
        infile = open(filepath, 'r+')
        source_content = infile.read()

        outfile = open(filepath, 'w')
        outfile.seek(0, 2)
        outfile.write(output)
        infile.close()
        outfile.close()

root = Tk()
root.grid()

var = StringVar()

e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=var, width=70).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=20)

b1 = Button(root, text="Browse", command=lambda:var.set(tkFileDialog.askdirectory())).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=7, pady=20)


L1 = Label(root, text="Source Directory:").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, pady=20)


b2 = Button(root, text='Start', command=style_check).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, padx=2, pady=10)

b3 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, padx=2, pady=10)

mainloop( )
```

When I run this script I am getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ram\Multi-files-gui\multifiles.py", line 11, in style_check
    source = e1.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`grid`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) method of every Tkinter widget works in-place and therefore returns `None`.  This means that you need to call it on its own line:

```
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=var, width=70)
el.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=20)
```

Otherwise, `e1` will be assigned to `None` and calling `e1.get` will raise an `AttributeError` because `None` does not have a `get` method.